# How pull image from GCP Artifact Registry in k8s deployment.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

Dou you know how to pull image from GCP Artifact Registry in k8s deployment.yaml?

Answer (score 1):

If your Kubernetes cluster is on GKE, then give the appropriate permissions to the Service account used by the cluster so that I can pull the images.

In the image field of your deployment YAML, provide the Image location which is basically

```
HOSTNAME/PROJECT-ID/TARGET-IMAGE:TAG
```

Hostname can be one of - `gcr.io, us.gcr.io, eu.gcr.io, asia.gcr.io` based on you location. Check https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#tag

If your cluster is out of Google Cloud, you'll need to set `imagePullSecrets` i.e. :

- Create a service account key, with JSON credentials, from your Google Cloud Console, navigate to APIs and Services -> Credentials, and create a new Service account key (Give the appropriate Role)
- Use this command to tell Kubernetes to use the JSON credentials when pulling images:

```bash
kubectl -n=NAMESPACE_NAME create secret docker-registry SECRET_NAME \
    --docker-server HOST_NAME \
    --docker-username _json_key \
    --docker-email ANY_VALID_EMAIL \
    --docker-password="$(cat ~/key.json)"
```

- Now either add the secrets to your YAML or the default service account used by k8s

To add to the default account:

```bash
kubectl patch serviceaccount default \
    -p '{"imagePullSecrets": [{"name": "SECRET_NAME"}]}'
```

OR add to your YAML

```
.
.
spec:
 containers:
   - name: my-container
     image: IMAGE_LOCATION
 imagePullSecrets:
   - name: SECRET_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variables like : **gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$BRANCH_NAME:$SHORT_SHA**

So it will be structured that way. If you are looking forward to automating and deploying to GKE or Cloud Run you can check my repo.

https://github.com/harsh4870/basic-ci-cd-cloudbuild refer the **couldbuild.yaml** file for more.

Based on datacenter you can use the tag : https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/pushing-and-pulling#tag

If you want to authenticate you have to use the **imagepull** secret if not using the GKE or cloud Run.

[Authentication documentation if using AKS, EKS, OKE, On-prem](https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication)

Answer (score -1):

pass the GCP artifact repo link like a usual docker repo link, for example

```
gcr.io/obi-wan416/volt-source:voltactivedata-client
```

**repo:imagename:imagetag**

Answer (score -1):

Create a imagepullsecret this must have key for a service account which can pull image from GCR. A service account which has `roles/storage.objectViewer` permission will be able to pull the image from GCR. Once this is done configure your manifest file for Kubernetes as shown below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  containers:
  - name: hello
    image: asia.gcr.io/<personal-id>/<gcr-repo>:latest
  imagePullSecrets:
  - name: <secret-nam>
```